А docker compose for SQL Server and ASP.NET
I'm facing a problem, I'm creating a docket compose for SQL Server and ASP.NET applications, but when the application is launched, it does not connect to the server
docker-compose:
version: '3.4'

 services:
       web-site1:
         image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}website1
         build:
           context: .
           dockerfile: Web-site1/Dockerfile
         environment:
          CONNECTION_STRING: "Server=sqlserver;Database=Web-site2;User Id=sa;Password=191202G@v"
         ports:
           - "8080:8080"
           - "8081:8081"
         depends_on:
           - sqlserver

      sqlserver:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      SA_PASSWORD: "191202G@v"
    volumes:
      - sqlserverdata:/var/opt/mssql/data
      - sqlserverlog:/var/opt/mssql/log
volumes:
  sqlserverdata:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: "F:/Progect/Web-site1/Web-site1/bin/Release/net8.0/publish/sqlserverdata"
  sqlserverlog:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: "F:/Progect/Web-site1/Web-site1/bin/Release/net8.0/publish/sqlserverlog"

**Connect link: **
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "Server=sqlserver;Database=Web-site2;User Id=sa;Password=191202G@v"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:5156"
      }
    }
  }
}

I think the problem is in the connection method

At the same time, when connected using the IDE, everything works

What's the error you're getting? To me, Server=sqlserver looks strange, it should be localhost or something

Aside... the SA_PASSWORD environment variable has been deprecated for some time now, you should be using MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD instead as per the mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server documentation.

The indenting of your docker-compose.yml file doesn't look correct.

When you say the application doesn't connect to the SQL Server instance how do you know that? What error message(s) are you getting? Unless you're somehow registering a custom X.509 certificate in the instance then it's going to be using the default self-signed certificate. Have you tried including ;TrustServerCertificate=true in your connection string?

@siggemannen nope, not localhost... not unless SQL Server is installed in the same container as the application trying to use it. In this case sqlserver is the service name that other containers in the composition can use to connect.

There doesn't seem to be any configuration/initialisation script involved to create the Web-site2 database, where is that happening? Database names specified in connection strings must exist already - it won't automatically create one on the first connection attempt and will instead give the client a generic 18456 Login failure message. You'll probably see in the instance's error log that it reports State numbers 38 or 46 which indicates, Couldn't find database requested by user.

@AlwaysLearning oh, I misread the config and thought they were installed on same docker. Time to dust off those container books :)

@AlwaysLearning
That's right, I forgot about initialization
